# Class component is rerendering in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api

I'm trying to build a simple youtube app using `youtube-api-search`. There's two main portion of the app ie. *VideoDetail* & *VideoList*. *VideoDetail* is intended to show/play the video whereas *VideoList* is for displaying a list of five videos with their titles.

Now, the issue is, top section of my app ie. is getting re-rendered continuously inside a loop. I cant figure out why that is. I app is really simple it doesn't even have any lifecycle methods. Please help me to figure out the error.

App.js (It is imported into index.js where it gets rendered)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';
import VideoDetail from './components/video_detail';

const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyC----key------N7khtCs';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      videos: [],
      selectedVideo: null
     };
     console.log('sth.');
    YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'surfboards'}, (videos) => {
      this.setState({
        videos: videos,
        selectedVideo: videos[0]
      });
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log('indexx')}

        <VideoDetail video={this.state.selectedVideo} />
        <VideoList
          onVideoSelect={selectedVideo => this.setState({selectedVideo})}
          videos={this.state.videos}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default App;
```

video_detail.js

```
import React from 'react';

const VideoDetail = ({video}) => {    //accesssing props elements direcly

    if(!video){
        return <div>Loading Details</div>;
    }

    const videoId = video.id.videoId;
    const url = `https//www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`;

    return (
        <div className="video-detail col-md-8">
            <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe className="embed-responsive-item" src={url}></iframe>
            </div>
            <div className="details">
                <div>{video.snippet.title}</div>
                <div>{video.snippet.description}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default VideoDetail;
```

video_list.js

```
import React from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';

const VideoList = props => {
    const videoItems = props.videos.map((video) => {
        console.log(video);
        return (
            <VideoListItem
                onVideoSelect={props.onVideoSelect}
                key={video.etag}
                video={video} />
            );
    });

    return (
        <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
            {videoItems}
        </ul>
    );
};

export default VideoList;
```

video_list_item.js

```
import React from 'react';

const VideoListItem = ({video, onVideoSelect}) => {    //pulling from props
    const imageUrl = video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;

    return(
        <li onClick={() => onVideoSelect(video)} className="list-group-item">
            <div className="video-list media">
                <div className="media-left">
                    <img className="media-object" src={imageUrl} />
                </div>
                <div className="media-body">
                    <div className="media-heading">{video.snippet.title}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    );
}

export default VideoListItem;
```

Someone, please explain me what is the issue here. I want to understand.

Comment: can you show your videoListItem component

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri updated my ques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue:

I was because `:` was not present in the url.

const url = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`;